# Caching not Working in Cassandra

Tags: caching, cassandra, solandra

I dont seem to have any caching enabled when checking in Opscenter or cfstats.  Im running Cassandra 1.1.7 with Solandra on Debian.  I have set the required global options in cassandra.yaml:

```
key_cache_size_in_mb: 800
key_cache_save_period: 14400
row_cache_size_in_mb: 800
row_cache_save_period: 15400
row_cache_provider: SerializingCacheProvider
```

Column Families were created as follows:

```
create column family example
with column_type = 'Standard'
and comparator = 'BytesType'
and default_validation_class = 'BytesType'
and key_validation_class = 'BytesType'
and read_repair_chance = 1.0
and dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.0
and gc_grace = 864000
and min_compaction_threshold = 4
and max_compaction_threshold = 32
and replicate_on_write = true
and compaction_strategy = 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'
and caching = 'ALL';
```

Opscenter shows no data available on caching graphs and CFSTATS doesn't show any cache related fields:

```
Column Family: charsets
SSTable count: 1
Space used (live): 5558
Space used (total): 5558
Number of Keys (estimate): 128
Memtable Columns Count: 0
Memtable Data Size: 0
Memtable Switch Count: 0
Read Count: 61381
Read Latency: 0.123 ms.
Write Count: 0
Write Latency: NaN ms.
Pending Tasks: 0
Bloom Filter False Postives: 0
Bloom Filter False Ratio: 0.00000
Bloom Filter Space Used: 16
Compacted row minimum size: 1917
Compacted row maximum size: 2299
Compacted row mean size: 2299
```

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caching stats have been moved from cfstats to info in Cassandra 1.1.  If you run nodetool info you should see something like:

```
Key Cache : size 5552 (bytes), capacity 838860800 (bytes), 38 hits, 47 requests, 0.809 recent hit rate, 14400 save period in seconds
Row Cache : size 0 (bytes), capacity 838860800 (bytes), 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 15400 save period in seconds
```

This is because there are now global caches, rather than per-CF.  It seems that Opscenter needs updating for this change - maybe there is a later version available that will work.